# nvd3 scatterPlot with rCharts in R: Increase Font size of labels?

Tags: r, rcharts, nvd3.js

I am trying to increase the font size of the x and y axis in the plot created using
NVD3 and rCharts. Here is my code for the plot. Any help is appreciated.

```
n1 <- nPlot(pValues~Chr,data=dat,type="scatterChart",height=400,width=750)
n1$chart(tooltipContent= "#! function(key, x, y, e){
         return '<b>ID:</b> ' + e.point.ID
         } !#")
n1$chart(forceY = c(0,8))
n1$chart(forceX = c(0,10))
#n1$chart(color = '#! function(d){return d.pValues} !#')
n1$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Chromosome')
n1$yAxis(axisLabel = '-log P value')
```

Comment: right now the easiest way is to add css as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883017/adjusting-axis-labels-nvd3-graph-in-rcharts , but I know this is probably not a workable solution.  I will try to work on another way and provide an answer that works straight from R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I think I discovered a solution thanks to [this stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript).  Let me know if it works for you. Change the `font-size`  to whatever you would like.  You could also provide a full set of CSS to change style, location, color, etc.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  pValues = runif(20,0,5),
  Chr = 1:20,
  ID = sample(LETTERS[1:20])
)

n1 <- nPlot(pValues~Chr,data=dat,type="scatterChart",height=400,width=750)
n1$chart(tooltipContent= "#! function(key, x, y, e){
     return '<b>ID:</b> ' + e.point.ID
     } !#")
n1$chart(forceY = c(0,8))
n1$chart(forceX = c(0,10))
#n1$chart(color = '#! function(d){return d.pValues} !#')
n1$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Chromosome')
n1$yAxis(axisLabel = '-log P value')
n1

n1$setTemplate(afterScript = '<script>
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".nv-axislabel { font-size: 15px; }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
</script>'
)
n1

n1$chart(margin = list(left=100)) 
n1

### as stated in comments, x is basically unworkable but this kind of works

n1$xAxis(
  axisLabel = 'Chromosome'
  ,tickFormat = "#!function(d){return d + "        " }!#"  #add space to the number
  ,rotateLabels=90                                         #rotate tick labels
)
n1$setTemplate(afterScript = '<script>
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".nv-x .nv-axislabel { font-size: 50px; }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
  css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".nv-y .nv-axislabel { font-size: 50px; }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
 </script>'
)
n1$chart(margin=list(left=100,bottom=100))
n1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, It's working for me but now i have another problem. **The axis labels are going beyond the plot area** so, i have  to define plot margins now. Can you help me ?? I am good at R but i don't know any javascript or html.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334863/rcharts-how-to-add-axis-lables-and-headings-to-nvd3-chart.  For `y`, solution is fairly easy `n1$chart(margin=list(left=100))` so change the 100 to a size that works.  I am still working on `x` since the obvious ways do not work, such as `n1$chart(margin=list(left=100,bottom=100))`.

Comment: I actually can't find a good way to handle `x` since nvd3 does not allow this to be set.  Also, I can change manually in script but it gets changed back on any resize event.  Just to show something that works, but I think unacceptably, I added more code in my previous answer that rotates the x tick labels with spaces, but I do not really consider it viable.