# Formatting axis titles in rPlot from rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm pretty new to R, and I'm trying to use rPlot from rCharts to generate a scatter plot. Everything works very well, but the plot axis labels are tiny, and I can't find a way to change the font size. Is there an easy way to set this?

nPlot seems to have more options for formatting axis fonts, but I find that generating my plot with nPlot is too slow for my application.

Comment: This was asked and answered in question 24493457

Comment: I've actually tried to implement this solution, and it did not affect the font size in my figures. I thought it may be a difference between using nPlot as in the question and using rPlot (which is what I have). I tried: g1 <- rPlot(...), g1$setTemplate(afterScript='<style> svg text {font-size: 9px;}</style>'), as well as the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334339/.